# Непонятное поведение разметки диалога в RV adapter

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter, android-xml, android-dialog

Имеется такая разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/change_status"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/test_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_view1" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/status_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view1"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/status_list"
            android:background="@color/test_color" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/remove_note"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="4.98"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/delete_mess"
                android:textColor="#CD0000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.04"
                android:background="@color/test_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/add_note_to_archive"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="4.98"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/archive_menu_item"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cancel_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@android:string/cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

имеется список в фрагменте со своим адаптером. У элемента списка есть view при нажатии на который показывается диалог:

```
holder.changeStatusTv.setOnClickListener {
            val dialogue = Dialog(ctx)
            dialogue.setContentView(R.layout.note_status_dialogue)

            val window = dialogue.window
            val wlp = window!!.attributes
            wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
            window.attributes = wlp

            dialogue.findViewById<View>(R.id.remove_note).setOnClickListener {
                showDialogue(1, recordModel.id, holder.adapterPosition)
                dialogue.dismiss()
            }

            dialogue.findViewById<View>(R.id.add_note_to_archive).setOnClickListener {
                showDialogue(2, recordModel.id, holder.adapterPosition)
                dialogue.dismiss()
            }

            if (statusList[0] == ctx.resources.getString(R.string.all_records_notepad)) {
                statusList.removeAt(0)
            }


            val list: ListView = dialogue.findViewById(R.id.status_list)


            for (i in 0 until statusList.size) {
                if (statusList.size > ctx.resources.getStringArray(R.array.basic_status_list).size) {
                    if (i < ctx.resources.getStringArray(R.array.basic_status_list).size) {
                        if (statusList[i] == ctx.resources.getStringArray(R.array.basic_status_list)[i]) {
                            statusList[i] = ctx.resources.getStringArray(R.array.status_list)[i]
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (statusList[i] == ctx.resources.getStringArray(R.array.basic_status_list)[i]) {
                        statusList[i] = ctx.resources.getStringArray(R.array.status_list)[i]
                    }
                }

            }


            list.adapter = ArrayAdapter(ctx, R.layout.note_status_layout, R.id.textItem, statusList)

            list.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
                changeStatus(recordModel.id, position)
                dialogue.dismiss()
            }

            dialogue.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
            dialogue.findViewById<View>(R.id.cancel_dialog).setOnClickListener {
                dialogue.dismiss()
            }

            Objects.requireNonNull<Window>(dialogue.window).setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            dialogue.show()
        }
```

Суть проблемы - на эмуляторе с версией api 26 (8.0) данный диалог размещается корректно по ширине и высоте родителя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а на эмуляторе с версией api 28 (9.0) диалог размешается по высоте родителя, а ширина ведет себя вообще непонятно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше я пробовал на реальных устройствах: android 10.0 и 6.0.1 и ситуация такая же как и на втором эмуляторе, хотя версии осей разные.  Вообще не могу понять что происходит с этим макетом, может у кого-то будут предположения или где-то ошибка есть?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге я так и не понял что происходит с этой разметкой :) Но проблему решить удалось, добавляем при создании диалога параметры окна:

```
wlp.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
```

но так получается что окошко на всю ширину экрана, а я пытаюсь добиться эффекта плавающего окошко. Для этого ставим в xml margin:

```
 android:layout_margin="20dp"
```

и все получается красиво.

P.S. Если кто-то поймет в чем причина такого поведения, то буду рад если объясните в чем проблема :)